# Expression.Call ignoring Null values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to ignore null values when using

```
MethodInfo equalsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
Expression.Call(member, equalsMethod,Expression.Constant(filter.Value.ToString().ToUpper()));
```

because I am getting object reference because of null values in database.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114845/handle-null-ref-exceptions-in-linq-expression-calls

Comment: Call the static string.Equals instead which takes two string parameters.